# Time is getting reset to old value in CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, date-time, esxi, centos-6

I have installed CentOS 6.2 in a VM on ESX & whenever I change the time to the appropriate value using date & hwclock command it's getting changed for that session. Once I restart the instance it's again getting reset to the old value of some time in year 2010.

What might be the reason?? I don't have access to ESX currently so I couldn't check what is the time in ESX server. Does the time in ESX server will be the reason for this?? If so is it not possible to change the time in VM alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time on the ESX is different from the time you are trying to set and if the VMWare tools are configured to sync the time that will indeed be the reason.

The [VMWare KB article on time keeping best practices](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427) has all the details you need.